# If you'll pick up some snacks, I'll get the beer

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

*If you'll pick up some snacks, I'll get the beer.*

In this sentence there is used the volitive "will" as I was thought by StoneyB in his exhaustive reply to my latest question here (["Would" in a backshifted reported context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70045/would-in-a-backshifted-reported-context)). This sentence can be paraphrased in this way: "If you are willing to take care of getting snacks, I am willing to reciprocate by providing the beer". But I am not able to see the difference between this sentence and the standard conditional clause, i.e. "If you pick up some snacks, I'll get the beer". Every conditional clause after all includes a reciprocal aspect. Can you please give me some other examples ot the volitive "will" in the sentence.

Comment: I think in "if you pick up some snacks..." you have a clear sequence of events. The first "pick up" is in Present Indefinite tense, which denotes "past in the future".  First the snacks are picked up, then the beer.  You essentially say "I need to see the snacks before I act on my promise (about the beer)".  The "will - will" sentence has no sequencing.

Comment: here? where? Link is missing.

Comment: "If you will lie back and stop screaming for novocaine, I can finish this root canal" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no practical difference between "If you pick up the snacks, I'll pick up the beer" and "If you will pick up . . .".

But in other contexts *will* is prohibited in *IF* clauses.

> If line power ∗*will* drop, the system will switch to battery power. ... *This must be expressed as*
> If line power **drops**, the system will switch to battery power.
>
> If you ∗*will* touch that knife I will shoot you.  ... *This must be expressed as*
> If you **touch** that knife I will shoot you.

There are three circumstances in which *will* is permitted in *IF* clauses:

- When *will* bears a volitive sense, "be willing". *If you will slice the pie, I'll get forks.*
- When *will* bears a habitual sense, "make a practice of". *If you **will** tease the cat you must expect to be scratched.*
- When the clause accepts a future event as certain.  *If (as you tell us) the auditors will be here on Tuesday, we'd better clean up the books*.

Comment: I tried to think of a counter-example when the subject is a person, but I couldn't come up with one. Many thanks for *If you touch that knife*!

Comment: The OP's example, "if you will pick up some snacks, I'll get the beer", then, falls under your first "circumstance", yes?  Is it customary then to avoid contracting "will"?

Comment: @VictorBazarov 1) Yes. 2) No, except that in the use of habitual *will* in the cat sentence *will* must be strongly stressed. I wrote these *wills* out for pedagogic clarity.

Comment: Note also that the habitual sense (teasing the cat) is British usage.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Exclusively? My mother would have been surprised to hear that!

Comment: Not knowing your mother @StoneyB, I can't comment on that, ;)
But it's not something I've ever seen/heard in American: conversation, media, or novels. Only in British English.